# How was Gia still texting Jake W if she was dead?

Tags: boo-bitch

in *Boo, Bitch* Gia was still texting Jake W even though she was dead, and how was she connected to Gavin? She told Erika she asked Jake W to prom so how could he not see her?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You seem to have 3 separate questions here; how could Gia text Jake, how was she connect to Gavin, and how come Jake couldn't see her.  Please only as 1 question per post; since you ask about texting in the title, that should be the question in the body of the post as well.  This would be improved by some descriptions of the times when Gia texts Jake, to establish that it is objectively happening.

Comment: Yes, please split this. I know the answer to at least two of the questions, but I can't answer it until it is split.